# Does Ubuntu Server have any special preinstalled packages

Tags: server, preinstallation

I want to build up my own desktop environment (like an Openbox/i3 setup) from a base. I don't want any pre-existing DE since I want to learn about all the components required to make a running DE on my own. Now the only "flavour" that Ubuntu offers in this respect is "Ubuntu Server". Now, my question is whether the Ubuntu Server ISO comes with any server-oriented stuff preinstalled. As far as I understand it is supposed to be very bare, but the website isn't very verbose about what comes preinstalled. So does it have anything like Apache, Docker, network-management tools etc preinstalled that I'd have to remove? Also, could someone point me to where the preinstalled packages are listed?

Edit:
Version which I am interested in is 20.04, the current LTS release. Also, the "minimal" install offered is standard Ubuntu with the DE, just stripped down to very small number of apps such as a web browser. That is not what I want. I want no preinstalled DE. I am fine with installing stuff from the Server ISO, I just need to know if there are really "server" stuff that I'd have no need for. Unless I know they exist and what they are, I can't remove them. Hence the question.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a release, some releases have a minimal option (ie. you start with enough to boot a system, plus packages you select).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD  or  for later releases also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264128/how-to-do-a-minimal-install-of-20-04

Comment: Ubuntu server comes with some Ubuntu special stuff that you don't really *need* for a server. Have you had a look at Arch? It has a  bare bones installer and a supportive community. I suggest you start with a VM install though. You will learn much about what it takes to make a server but the way is fraught.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a minimal install of 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264128/how-to-do-a-minimal-install-of-20-04)

Comment: If you want to see what's on an ISO, have a look at it's manifest... it contains a list of the packages included (plus version details; which you can look into further as required...)

Comment: Don't forget there are two minimals... the Desktop ISO offers a minimal option which is nothing more than full-install & a package-removal script run post-install  (*which is why it takes longer than full install; it does more work; it was added as users requested it*).  That is **not** the minimal install I was referring to which is a true minimal install

Comment: @guiverc I had indeed gotten confused which minimal install you were referring to. But in any case, the 20.04 release no longer has a minimal install in the sense you were talking of and trying to make it work is too long a path for my purposes. I am perfectly fine with removing any additional packages from the standard Server install but for some reason it's just hard to find a listing of the preinstalled packages on the website.

Comment: The list of packages available on the ISO are on the manifest, however which packages you get installed will depend on what options you select during the actual install (esp. if online & opt to download extra options).  Off hand the main difference I'm aware of is Ubuntu Server uses netplan.io, where as I believe all desktop installs use NetworkMnager; but as you install packages for desktop systems, you may get NM packages installed anyway due to *dep* rules...  (though not being an i3 user I don't know those packages; but it wouldn't be a requirement of `openbox` you mention either)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out each Ubuntu release has a `.manifest` file associated with it on its downloads page which, according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50077/how-to-get-a-list-of-preinstalled-packages), lists the preinstalled packages. However, there are comments in the same source saying that it's the list of the live CD packages. As that is the closest answer I got, I compared the manifest files of Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Ubuntu Desktop 20.04. There are indeed a few packages which are present in Ubuntu server but not in the Desktop such as screen, tmux, eatmydata, curl and a bunch of python packages. Some packages have different versions. Nothing big is preinstalled though. Here is a link to the [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/xXqw56Yu).

Comment: Ubuntu Server is designed to be a general-purpose server for general-purpose use. It's not designed to be lightweight and sparse. It's not designed to be bloated and super-featured. It's the base upon which you install the specific services you want.

Answer (score 5):

I might have misread your question initially, since you are asking about "preinstalled". My answer is more in the line of "what can be removed" and then "what can be installed".

By default, Ubuntu server is pretty minimal, and you normally shouldn't have to remove anything. However, there are a few packages and snaps that are safe to remove, but this is not really documented anywhere.

For reference, I consider the following packages safe to remove under all circumstances: (unless you really need them - I have removed all those on my server)

- lxd-agent-loader
- cloud-init
- byobu
- vim
- xfsprogs
- xauth (probably needed if you want a GUI)

One "official" place to get a list of packages available during installation (but not preinstalled unless you choose to) is the ["Using the installer step by step"](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/step-by-step) guide for Ubuntu Server.

In this guide you'll find this image, which shows packages that you are presented for during installation: (which also means these are not preinstalled, unless you choose to)

[image]

And now for the caveat: Since 20.04, these are all Snap packages. It seems Canonical are indeed pushing snaps in front of regular `.deb` packages.

However, to get an overview of available packages you can install afterwards (which are not snaps), you can consult the official [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs). This guide has installation instructions for many useful server applications and utilites, which you can find by navigating the left-hand menu.

Finally, for installing a desktop environment on a server, I find this [existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui) most useful.

Comment: Yup. The pushing of snaps is why I'm leaving Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a light graphical alternative for a server at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398)

Comment: Please note that [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/mini.iso) is still available for 20.04 LTS. No snaps, no problems here :)